# Hexadecimal value of c++ enum in doxygen documentation

Tags: c++, enums, documentation, doxygen

i have some problem with doxygen documentation.

I want to have something like

E_SOME_ERROR | 0x000001 Detailed info about this error

Important think is that I need values generated by doxygen but I can't find any solution. Do you guys know if this is possible?

So for example

```c
/**
 * @brief Enum with error codes.
 */
enum enumName
{
    ONE, /**< {HEX value} - 1st number */
    TWO, /**< {HEX value} - 2nd number */
    THREE, /**< {HEX value} - 3rd number */
    FOUR, /**< {HEX value} - 4th number */
}
```

Should be generated in pdf like:

```
--------------------------------
| ONE    | 0x0001 - 1st number |
--------------------------------
| TWO    | 0x0002 - 2nd number |
--------------------------------
| THREE  | 0x0003 - 3rd number |
--------------------------------
| FOUR   | 0x0004 - 4th number |
--------------------------------
```

And each {HEX value} have to be generated by some macro or something like this not hardcoded.

Comment: Have you posted to the Doxygen group?

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Can you give a little bit more of an example, it is unclear where this example is / what the intentions are. What kinde of values are you talking about in " I need values generated by doxygen"?

Comment: Interesting idea,, though doxygen is not a compiler an can't calculate it without a large effort. When e.g `TEN` would be defined in the enum as `ONE + 9` would you expect doxygen to calculate the value as well? Interesting issue is in this context though: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8256 and the pull request https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/8266.

Comment: Yes i need doxygen to calculate since i have sections in my enum for different scopes and there are gaps for example i have 1,2,3 and 101,102,103. In documentation i would like to find number that i received from logs.